# What is use of azure functions AzureWebJobsStorage and AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType settings

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-functions

Can you  please help me to understand what is use of  azure functions **AzureWebJobsStorage** and **AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType**  settings.

I am new to Azure , So please say answer through an example .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [`official documentation`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-my/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings):

> **AzureWebJobsSecretStorageType**
>
> Specifies the repository or provider to use for key storage. Currently, the supported repositories are blob storage ("Blob") and the local file system ("Files"). The default is blob in version 2 and file system in version 1.
>
> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for all functions except for HTTP triggered functions. The storage account must be a general-purpose one that supports blobs, queues, and tables.

Comment: Its worth mentioning that there is a lot of API's like in Logic Apps that do NOT support Blob storage for that yet.

Comment: Also worth being aware of this -> https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Changes-to-Key-Management-in-Functions-V2
The implication is that while 'Blob' is now the default in v2 (and presumably v3), 'Blob' key storage is currently not compatible with the ARM function `listkeys`.